# How to pass the radio button value to other program and insert value into database using php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form with multiple radio buttons. What i want to store the radio button values in database like 1 for "Yes" and 0 for "No". I am using couple of script a.php, b.php for the same, a.php will get the radio button values and pass to b.php as parameter. Then b.php insert into the database. The problem here is database field for button value always updating with 0. I tried to implement with javascript and some other php logic. But no luck. Also I have created other small script to test the radio value is printing properly which is working fine. The problem is I am not aware how to get proper value in "recommend" in b.php

I really appreciate your help.

a.php is like below:

```
<div id="result">
<label for="sel1">Would You recomend</label>
                    <div class="pull-left">

  <input name='recommend' type='radio' value=1>Yes

  <input name='recommend' type='radio' value=0>No 

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
```

b.php

```
<?php
require_once './config.php';

$pid = intval($_POST["pid"]);
$uid = intval($_POST["uid"]);
$score = intval($_POST["score"]);
$recommend = intval($_POST["recommend"]);

$aResponse['error'] = FALSE;
$aResponse['message'] = '';
$aResponse['updated_rating'] = '';

$return_message = "";
$success = FALSE;


$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_product_rating` (`product_id`, `user_id`, `ratings_score`, `recommend_score`) VALUES "
        . "( :pid, :uid, :score, :recommend)";
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

try {

  $stmt->bindValue(":pid", $pid);
  $stmt->bindValue(":uid", $uid);
  $stmt->bindValue(":score", $score);
 $stmt->bindValue(":recommend", $recommend);

  //$stmt->execute(':pid' => $pid, ':uid' => $uid, ':score' => $score, ':recommend' => $recommend));
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->rowCount();
  if ($result > 0) {
    $aResponse['message'] = "Your rating has been added successfully";
  } else {
    $aResponse['error'] = TRUE;
    $aResponse['message'] = "There was a problem updating your rating. Try again later";
  }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  $aResponse['error'] = TRUE;
  $aResponse['message'] = $ex->getMessage();
}

if ($aResponse['error'] === FALSE) {
  // now fetch the latest ratings for the product.
  $sql = "SELECT count(*) as count, AVG(ratings_score) as score FROM `tbl_products_ratings` WHERE 1 AND product_id = :pid";
  try {
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":pid", $pid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $products = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if ($products[0]["count"] > 0) {
      // update ratings
      $aResponse['updated_rating'] = "Average rating <strong>" . round($products[0]["score"], 2) . "</strong> based on <strong>" . $products[0]["count"] . "</strong> users";
    } else {
      $aResponse['updated_rating'] = '<strong>Ratings: </strong>No ratings for this product';
    }
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    #echo $ex->getMessage();
 }
}

echo json_encode($aResponse);
?>
```

Jquery which I am using in a.php to send radio button value to b.php:

```
<script>
$document.ready(function(){
 $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
 var recommend = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
 url:"b.php",
 method:"POST",
 data:{recommend:recommend},
// data:{recommend:$('#recommend').val($("[type='radio'] :checked").val())},
 success: function(data){
 $('#result').html(data);
 }
 });
 });
});
</script>
```

jquery to fetch pid,uid,score..

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
<?php
if (!isset($USER_ID)) {
  ?>
      alert("You need to have a account to rate?");
      return false;
<?php } else { ?>

      var score = $("#score").val();
      if (score.length > 0) {
        $("#rating_zone").html('processing...');
        $.post("update_ratings.php", {
          pid: "<?php echo $_GET["pid"]; ?>",
          uid: "<?php echo $USER_ID; ?>",
          score: score

        }, function(data) {
          if (!data.error) {
            // success message
            $("#avg_ratings").html(data.updated_rating);
            $("#rating_zone").html(data.message).show();
          } else {
            // failure message
            $("#rating_zone").html(data.message).show();
          }
        }, 'json'
                );
      } else {
        alert("select the ratings.");
      }

<?php } ?>
  });
</script>
```

I can insert the value 1 if "YES" for radio button with the mentioned jquery but it's inserting 0 for other fields like product_id..etc.I want just one entry to be inserted in db with proper value of radio button along with other fields.I have provided the full code for insert (b.php) with ajax which passing value to b.php from a.php. Kindly suggest.

I want output in mysql like below:

```
ratings_id product_id user_id ratings_score recommend_score
1          17637       1      4              0

2          17638       2      2              1
```

How it's happening now:

```
ratings_id product_id user_id ratings_score recommend_score
    3           0         0       0              1

    6           17639     2      4              0
```

Comment: For one thing, ID's are meant to be unique. Check your HTML.

Comment: you have twice the same `id`: `id='newsletter'` - that won't work.

Comment: The HTML is also incomplete.

Comment: You also posted this already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522595/how-to-pass-the-radio-button-value-in-php-to-other-program-and-insert-value-in

Comment: when you click the radio, then the ajax is fired which _does not include_ values for pid, uid, ... You have to add them there too.

Answer (score 0):

Change id to class attribute.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
            var recommend = $(this).val();
            console.log(recommend);
            $.ajax({
                url:"b.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{
                    recommend:recommend
                },
                success: function(data){
                   //your code here
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>
 <input name="recommend" class='newsletter' type='radio' value=1>Yes

 <input name="recommend" class='newsletter' type='radio' value=0>No
```

Comment: I have removed the name, id and added class attribute, but no luck. :(

Comment: try in ajax
`data:{recommend: $("input[type='radio'] :checked").val())`
if you have not another input radio tags on the page

Comment: I have commented all the other radio, except this one. Still the value is inserting as 0 and not 1, even I select Yes.

Comment: Yes name="recommend" must be in input radio. Now I edit my answer.
`let value = $("input[class='newsletter']:checked").val();
console.log(value);`
Switch must work.

Comment: Or use like in your code 
`let recommend = $(this).val();`

Comment: Would you mind to suggest where to place this in my script? I tried to to use let recommend = $(this).val(); instead of var recommend = $(this).val(); but not working. Thanks again

Comment: I edited my answer and added script. You must see value of radio input in browser console  when you will click.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax that fires once a user clicks on a radio-button you are not sending the other values needed for insert (pid, uid, score). I suppose they are included in the half-shown form.

Assuming you have those inputs in your form

```
<input name="pid" id="pid">
<input name="uid" id="uid">
<input name="score" id="score">
```

*EDIT*: since you've now shown more code I updated the code below (to match how you send pid & uid in the normal form-submit).

you can add them to the data object with something like this:

```
data:{
   recommend:recommend,
   pid: "<?php echo $_GET["pid"]; ?>",
   uid: "<?php echo $USER_ID; ?>",
   score: $('#score').val(),
},
```

Also change the double-ids of `#newsletter` as the others have suggested.

Comment: I am using other script to pass the uid,pid,score value to b.php. Please have a look and suggest. What is wrong with my code.

Comment: The other script is the normal form-submit. I updated this answer to match how you get and send pid & uid in that form. Anyhow, you need to include those values.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="color" id="rdoColor" value="green" />Green<br />
<input type="radio" name="color" id="rdoColor" value="Blue" />Blue<br />
```

**Sample JQuery Code:**

```
$(document).on("click", "input[id=rdoColor]", function(){

      $.post(serverPath+"/colorHandler.php", {action: "saveColor", color: $(this).val()}, function(data){
        var response = $.parseJSON(data); 
        // use this response as u need
      });
  });
```

**Sample PHP (colorHandler.php):**

```
$jsonStr = "";
define('DB_SERVER', 'DBserver:port');
define('DB_NAME', 'DBName');
define('DB_USER', 'dbUser');
define('DB_PASS', 'dbPass');

try {
    $dbCon = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $dbCon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO colorTable (colorName) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt= $dbCon->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST["color"]));

    if( $dbCon->lastInsertId() ){

        $jsonStr = '{
                "status":"Success",
                "Message":"Color Saved"
            }';
        echo $jsonStr;      
    }else{

        $jsonStr = '{
                "status":"Failure",
                "Message":"Color was not Saved"
            }';
        echo $jsonStr;      
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
        $jsonStr = '{
                    "status":"Failure",
                    "Message":"Database server not found!"
                }';
        echo $jsonStr;
}
```